# Reinitialize all publications

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a database with almost 20 publications, and every once or twice a week a random number of publications needs to be reinitialized.  I have to go and do it manually then every thing works as expected.

I'm using the following command to initialize publication:

```
exec sp_reinitsubscription @publication = 'PubName', @subscriber = 'all'
```

The problem is that I have create it for each publication one by one, 
so my question is, is there a way to execute it on all publications?

Comment: Did you see this `[ @publication = ] 'publication' Is the name of the publication. publication is sysname, with a default of all.` in [books online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-reinitsubscription-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sp_reinitsubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-reinitsubscription-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) states that the default for the `@publication` parameters is "all," so you can execute without that parameter to reinitialize all of the publications.

```
exec sp_reinitsubscription @subscriber = 'all'
```